# Show that a quadrilateral with perpendicular diagonals is circumscribing a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

> A quadrilateral $ABCD$ is given with $AC \perp BD$ and $AB\cdot CD=AD\cdot BC$. Show that $ABCD$ is circumscribing a circle.

$AC\perp BD \Rightarrow AB^2+CD^2=BC^2+AD^2$ and we also have $AB\cdot CD=AD \cdot BC$. How to use the equalities to get that $AB+CD=AD+BC$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the first and twice the second equalities one obtains:
$$
AB^2+2AB\cdot CD+CD^2=BC^2+2BC\cdot DA+DA^2\\
\implies (AB+CD)^2=(BC+DA)^2\\
\implies AB+CD=BC+DA.
$$